# integrating IM applications with outlook 2013, events(OnStateChanged etc) not working

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, lync-2013

I have implemented the IM Client (32 bits) for Outlook 2013 (64 bits) as per article "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396". IM APP is working well with outlook.

When there is a change in state & called the function StateChanged(). Now outlook should take the action for changing state. But there is no call from outlook. 
Please anybody help me why outlook is not calling the any API (like OnContactInformationChanged).

```
OnStateChanged += OnOnStateChanged ;
Public void StateChanged(){ 
        ClientState _previousClientState = this._State;
        this._State = ClientState.ucClientStateSignedOut;
        IMClientStateChangedEventData eventData = new IMClientStateChangedEventData(_previousClientState, this._State);
        //Raise the event for state change
        OnStateChanged(this as Client, eventData as     ClientStateChangedEventData);
}

public static void OnOnStateChanged(Client _eventSource,  ClientStateChangedEventData _eventData)
    {

    }
```

I also try to raise the OnContactInformationChanged() but no response from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

1. OnSateChanged/OnContactInformationChanged events is something what would be registered by Outlook when he does GetInterface & GetContactByUri calls.
2. You need to just raise the events when your LyncClient/Contact state/contactinformation is changed.
3. Careful while raising the events since we need to passed the event data and your event data will determine function would be called with which argument.

Comment: I am facing similar issue and I doubt that the data I am passing to the event are somehow not valid. As none of the events are working for me except OnShuttingDown event. Because OnShuttingDown event doesn't expect any data.
I am dealing other events on some new threads. Does it make a reason for events not working? If needed I can share my code for details.